# modified executeIndex in IndexSucces?

Tags: php, oop, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i have

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->plans = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Messages')
    ->createQuery('a')
    ->execute();
}
```

I can add `->limit(5);` and how can i this make in indexSuccess.php? for example i add:

```
<input type="text" id="limit">

<?php foreach ($messages as $i => $message): ?>
   echo $message->getId();
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

how to send data directly to executeNew?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific regarding your problem? I think you are trying to use some information defined in an action on a template but i'm not completly sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you define the property correctly in the action you can use it in the view:

```
public function executeIndex() {
   $this->messages = // whatever way you fetch the data
}
```

in the view you can now use the $messages variable.

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?